# sql server 2008 r2 port configuration paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, port

im wondering where I can find within a file on windows the path to sql server 2008 r2 where the port configuration is set? Is there such a thing?

Thanks

Comment: You could work this out with 5 minutes googling. There are three "file" places that I'm aware of: The registry, the SQL Server error log, the windows event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port(s) for the SQL Server service is configured using the "Sql Server Configuration Manager".  It is accessible from Start/Run and executing SqlServerManager10.msc.  (Later versions just increment the number to correspond with the version of SQL Server.)

Expand *SQL Server Network Configuration* on the left and select the *Protocols for* , right click on *TCP/IP Protocol* entry on the right and choose Properties.  The IP Addresses tab is where you see the port assigned to each IP.  Dynamic Port allocation is indicated by 0 in the TCP Dynamic Ports property for a given IP.

Here is a decent [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017) on how to change the port assignment if you need that.